# Is there a way to collect Kafka-metrics using Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

New to Kafka

I was wondering is there a way to get kafka-metrics using the java-api.  Here is what I mean by kafka-metrics:

1. List of topics
2. Number of messages in each topic-partition (including starting offset, ending offset)
3. List of brokers
4. Assuming I use the 0.9 consumer API and I let kafka to manage my consumer offsets, the offset of each consumer

I realize that, it is possible that only some of these are available, and they maybe available through different classes or approaches.  That's why I numbered each bullet point.

Comment: hba, was my answer helpful for you? can you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KafkaConsumer `listTopics()` method will solved the first one.
KafkaConsumer `metrics()` will give you the metrics for that consumer.
KafkaProducer `metrics()` will give you the metrics for that producer.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I am using Spring for my api. Using the below code, you can get the metrics via java.

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

private static final Logger LOGGER =
          LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);


@Autowired
  private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

      public void testlag() {
          for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
                    .getListenerContainers()) {
              Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics = messageListenerContainer.metrics();
              metrics.forEach( (clientid, metricMap) ->{
                  System.out.println("------------------------For client id : "+clientid);
                  metricMap.forEach((metricName,metricValue)->{
                      //if(metricName.name().contains("lag"))
                      System.out.println("------------Metric name: "+metricName.name()+"-----------Metric value: "+metricValue.metricValue());
                  });
              });
                }
      }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I know I am commenting on little old thread. Is there any other change required to invoke the metrics ? How the testlag method is invoked ? 
TIA